# Setting up sharepoint dev environment on azure?

Tags: sharepoint, azure

I would like to begin on development for sharepoint. 
Instead of setting up a dev environment on premise, I would like to set up one on Azure.

I've found some tutorials http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2013/09/26/create-sharepoint-2013-development-environments-quickly-on-azure.aspx but each on use Visual Studio RC. When I try to create one with Visual Studio Ultimate, there's no "Configure Developer Desktop" folder and I don't know how to set up tools and which tools?

Do you have a follow up or a virtual drive that I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the chance to have an msdn subscription, you can follow http://visualstudio2013msdngalleryimage.azurewebsites.net/

Best, you can subscribe to an office 365 account and more easily deploy to your new sharepoint site

Answer (score 1):

I have written this in detail using 3 staged approach. The first of the post is available at this link
http://wellytonian.com/2014/10/sharepoint-2013-development-platform-azure/. Basically you can setup a complete SharePoint 2013 standalone server, setup the point to site vpn and connect. Code away :)